# i dont want to refresh my list view after disable item in list view

Tags: android, listview

Actually I have 3 list views attached to button, I disabled item in list view and after disabling and if I move to another button and come back to previous button lists it is getting refresh list . I don't want to  refresh the list
, I want to show the disable item even though I move forward and come back to previous list.

Comment: post some code so we can see what you have did and what you want

Comment: I think when you disable the lists then detach adapters of the list pro-grammatically. This will ensure that lists does not have live Adapter. Only on click of a button, attach the adapter and refresh it. I think it will work.

Comment: actually i have 3 list attached to a screen vertically i am disabling the item in list view and after am going for another button list views . and if i come back to previous button list it is getting refresh list . i want disable item le it be i dont want to refresh the list view

Comment: for (int i = 0; i <new List .size(); i++) {
    if(i == position){ 
      v.setEnabled(false);
      v.setClickable(false);
      v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB")); }else if(i != position){ 
    }

Answer (score 0):

You need change the item info when you changed it's status，such as Callback Method. Then it won't change ever whatever you scroll the list.

Comment: i cant get you wt you said